# refresh_token implemented using web api 2 is not coming in the token response consistently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, refresh-token

I have implemented Refresh Token to refresh access_token using the link http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/ and when the code is deployed into load-balanced server, sometimes refresh_token is coming in the token response sometimes it is not. It is working fine in local environment. Can you please guide me where I am going wrong or how I can check any particular server is returning the invalid response. Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Same error here.

Comment: Well, that article requires you to implement some code in order to support this.  You need to post your relevant code, including how you've configured the OAuthServer